# Why does wx.EVT_SIZE fire only on maximize?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want it to fire whenever I resize the window. But it fires only on maximize and unmaximize.

How do I fix it to fire on every resize event?

I am working on Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity, if it's a relevant detail.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on how wx.EVT_SIZE works, but for now could you use wx.EVT_PAINT? http://zetcode.com/wxpython/events/

Comment: You should post some code that replicates this behavior. EVT_SIZE fires for any window resize.